# Convert String to Date and then Change that Date Format

Tags: android

I want convert string to Date and then change that date format to save in Date Object. Date will be automatically change their format.

```
try {
        String starttime = "10:00AM";
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mma", Locale.ENGLISH);
        Date startdat = format.parse(starttime);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

        Calendar startcalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        startcalendar.setTime(startdat);
        startcalendar.set(calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

        java.text.DateFormat simpleformat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SSSZ", Locale.US);

        String **time**=simpleformat.format(startcalendar.getTime());

        Log.e("taggg",String.valueOf(time));



    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("error",e.getMessage());
    }
```

I want **time** variable to save in Date Object with same format.

Comment: Can u share your expected output

Comment: My expected output is 2017-07-24 09:00:00.000 like that

Answer (score 0):

Check this I have updated

Just change this

```
java.text.DateFormat simpleformat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS", Locale.US);
```

So update

```
try {
            String starttime = "10:00AM";
            SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mma", Locale.ENGLISH);
            Date startdat = format.parse(starttime);
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

            Calendar startcalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            startcalendar.setTime(startdat);
            startcalendar.set(calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

            java.text.DateFormat simpleformat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS", Locale.US);

            String time=simpleformat.format(startcalendar.getTime());

            Log.e("taggg",String.valueOf(time));



        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("error",e.getMessage());
        }
```

Comment: When i was convert time to Date format with the help of parse() method, its change defalut format  Tue Aug 08 10:00:00 GMT+05:30 2017

Comment: Please be clear about your question what u got and what you are expecting

Comment: 2017-07-24 09:00:00.000 expected in that format but in Date Object

Comment: I already tried but not get, its save in string but not convert to Date Object